# Intune group policy for setting edge browser homepage

Tags: google-chrome, policy, intune

I have created configuration policy for home page start up for chrome browser, this is not opening, I have also tried for edge as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5xsS.png)

Can I please have assistance if there is a specific way of doing this